# Getting snowflake task runid

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to access task runId from task body.

```
CREATE TASK MY_TASK
    WAREHOUSE = COMPUTE_WH
    SCHEDULE = '60 minute'
AS
    CALL LOAD_USER_TABLE_PROC(this.taskRunID) # Passing task runId to procedure.
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the run_id is the epoch of when the root task was scheduled to execute.  If that is what you are looking for in the SP, it might be better to simply use the `TASK_HISTORY` table function for `MY_TASK` and limit the result to 1 record.  That would give you the current run_id.  You could do that from inside the `LOAD_USER_TABLE_PROC` procedure instead of trying to pass it in as a parameter.

Would that give you what you need?